# Linux passing continuous output as command line args

Tags: c++, linux, shell, command-line-arguments

I have a machine vision program (`./detectUpdateHomeML`) which continuously outputs the name of objects found to the terminal using the following code:

```
circle( img, center, radius, color, 3, 8, 0 );
if (circle) {  
  std::cout << " " << cascadeName << " " << timeFound() << endl;
  std::cout << std::flush;
}

int timeFound() {
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer [80];
  time (&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
  strftime (buffer,80," %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",timeinfo);
  std:cout << (buffer);
  eventCount++;
}
```

I am looking to send this input as command line arguments to a second program using back-ticks to capture the output and send it to the other program like so:

```
./acceptInput `./detectUpdateHomeML`
```

However the arguments don't seem to be getting passed to `./acceptInput`.

I have a test program called `./testInput` that simply prints `Hello World!` like so:

```
std::cout << "Hello World!";
```

When using the same command:

```
./acceptInput `./testInput`
```

The program works and outputs as expected:

```
There are 3 arguments:
0 ./acceptInput
1 Hello
2 World!
```

What is going wrong when I try to pass continuous output from `./detectUpdateHomeML` to the `./acceptInput` program?

Comment: What does "continuous" mean? Can you show the main loop? Does the main loop terminate when the standard input is closed?

Comment: If an object is detected a circle is drawn on the screen around the object, I just have an `if` statement that `if` the circle function is called to print the output, I'll update my question with the `if`.

Comment: In order to pass arguments to the `acceptInput` process this way, the process that generates these arguments must really terminate first. Does `detectUpdateHomeML` terminate, or is it supposed to keep running? Maybe you want to stream the data instead (`./detectUpdateHomeML | ./acceptInput`)? Or use `xargs` (`./detectUpdateHomeML | xargs -n2 ./acceptInput`)?

Comment: What happens when you run "echo ``./detectUpdateHomML``"? (with backticks. I can't seem to use them in the comment without them becoming markup).

Comment: Magnus Hoff, the `detectUpdateHomeML` needs to keep running, I'll try you methods and report back.

davmac, when I try that it just prints `./detectUpdateHomeML`

Comment: @Colin747, I guess you didn't catch my remark about the backticks, then? trying again: `echo \`./detectUpdateHomeML\``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `detectUpdateHomeML` produces events which you want to handle with `acceptInput`. In that case, you have a slight mismatch in your data flow which you can resolve with `xargs`, like so:

```
./detectUpdateHomeML | xargs -n2 ./acceptInput
```

---

When executing a program with arguments, the parent process (for example `bash`) needs to know how many arguments there are *before* starting execution, so when you do

```
./acceptInput `./detectUpdateHomeML`
```

`bash` *must* wait until `detectUpdateHomeML` has finished running before starting `acceptInput`.

In order to use the output from `detectUpdateHomeML` while it is still running, use pipes:

```
./detectUpdateHomeML | ...
```

This will redirect the output from `detectUpdateHomeML` to standard input of some program.

`xargs` accepts space-separated text in its input and executes subprocesses giving this text as arguments. Use `-n` to decide how many arguments are passed each time, for example `2`:

```
./detectUpdateHomeML | xargs -n2 ...
```

`xargs` also takes the name of the subprocess to execute:

```
./detectUpdateHomeML | xargs -n2 ./acceptInput
```

Now, every time `detectUpdateHomeML` generates two items of output, `acceptInput` will be executed with these two as arguments.

This will let you run `detectUpdateHomeML` continuously while `acceptInput` is executed every time `detectUpdateHomeML` has generated sufficient output. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Was just about to reply to your comment, this worked great. I'll need to fiddle with `-n2` option a bit to take account of the three outputs (or is it four including the first arg as `./detectUpdateHomeML`?) Many thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going about this the right way.  As `./detectUpdateHomeML` keeps running and outputting event information, it needs to be the standard input to `acceptInput`, not the latter's list of command-line arguments.  Then, you chain them in a pipeline rather than using back-ticks:

```
./detectUpdateHomeML | ./acceptInput
```

The reason you shouldn't use the command line and backticks is that when you do that, `./acceptInput` isn't even run until after `./detectUpdateHomeML` has terminated, generating all its output.

Separately, in...

```
std::cout << " " << cascadeName << " " << timeFound() << endl;
std::cout << std::flush;
```

...the second line's unnecessary as `endl` outputs a newline then flushes, so you're flushing a known-empty buffer.

Comment: `./acceptInput` is expecting them as command line arguments, when I try this is just prints `There are 1 arguments:
0 ./acceptInput` and then the machine vision program runs after.

Comment: Then change `acceptInput`... you can't have a program that produces "continuous output" get any of that to another program's command line until termination.